# Why won't the scrollTop property work on my event listener?

Tags: javascript, function, properties, event-handling

I am currently trying to get familiar with event listeners so I can implement one that toggles a class on my header when the page has been scrolled by a certain amount. I've read that scrollTop is a good tool to use in situations like this, however, when experimenting with it in a basic function, I can't seem to get it to do anything at all...

As I've understood it, the scrollTop property measures the displacement of the vertical scroll bar from position 0, in pixels, then returns it as a unitless integer.

With this in mind I expected the following code to output an alert on my webpage when the scrollbar exceeded 20 pixels from the initial position... Any help as to why this is not the case would be greatly appreciated!

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", handleclick);

function handleclick() {
  if (document.scrollTop > 20) {
    alert("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using scrollTop with document. If you console document.scrollTop it will give you undefined because document has no property named scrollTop. If you want to see the scrollTop in action you can set addEventListener to a particular element. For example:-

HTML

```
<div class="outer" id="outer">
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .outer {
    width: 15em;
    height: 5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

JS

```
 const outer = document.getElementById("outer");
 outer.addEventListener("scroll", handleclick);

 function handleclick() {
   console.log("scroll ",outer.scrollTop);
  }
```

May this above example helps you!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for your help!